# How to regex in a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, innodb

I have a simple task where I need to search a record starting with string characters and a single digit after them. What I'm  trying is this

```
SELECT trecord FROM `tbl` WHERE (trecord LIKE 'ALA[d]%')
```

And

```
SELECT trecord FROM `tbl` WHERE (trecord LIKE 'ALA[0-9]%')
```

But both of the queries always return a `null` record

```
trecord
-------
null
```

Where as if I execute the following query

```
SELECT trecord FROM `tbl` WHERE (trecord LIKE 'ALA%')
```

it returns

```
trecord
-------
ALA0000
ALA0001
ALA0002
```

It means that I have records that starts with ALA and a digit after it,

**EDIT**

I'm doing it using PHP MySQL and innodb engine to be specific.

Comment: Please always TAG your questions with the DB engine you are using. I can only guess it is MySQL.

Comment: Use this link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Comment: `LIKE` does not support regex. The only wildcards supported are `%` and `_` (at least in standard SQL and MySQL)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I think you can use [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) instead of LIKE

```
SELECT trecord FROM `tbl` WHERE (trecord REGEXP '^ALA[0-9]')
```

Comment: but it will search the records like `ALA101` and `BALA002`, and I only want `ALA101` to be searched

Comment: added the ^ in front of the regex. If you read in a bit about regular expressions you can do anything you want with it. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @Wietze314 i'm a little weak in regex, Thanks anyways

Comment: although it works but can you please guide me what is the use of `^` here? As far as I know it is being used as not to include something.. Where as the documentation says that it will `Match the beginning of a string.` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html .. I'm not sure how to elaborate this line of code `'^ALA[0-9]'`

Comment: Well, without `^` it will search every place in a string to find a pattern. Including it force to search string for pattern only from beginning - in other words string have to starts with pattern.

Comment: @zzlalani the `^` only means "not to include" when inside square brackets. Otherwise, it means "begins with".

Comment: The parenthesis are there for good style, but not strictly required, right?

Comment: the `` (quotes) are not required. The `[]` (parenthesis) are required, to make sure that a single digit after `ALA` matches the string.

Answer (score 6):

In my case (Oracle), it's `WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(column, 'regex.*')`. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_re.htm#1007573):

> **SQL Function**
>
> **Description**
>
> ---
>
> REGEXP_LIKE
>
> This function searches a character column for a pattern. Use this
>   function in the WHERE clause of a query to return rows matching the
>   regular expression you specify.
>
> ...
>
> REGEXP_REPLACE
>
> This function searches for a pattern in a character column and
>   replaces each occurrence of that pattern with the pattern you specify.
>
> ...
>
> REGEXP_INSTR
>
> This function searches a string for a given occurrence of a regular
>   expression pattern. You specify which occurrence you want to find and
>   the start position to search from. This function returns an integer
>   indicating the position in the string where the match is found.
>
> ...
>
> REGEXP_SUBSTR
>
> This function returns the actual substring matching the regular
>   expression pattern you specify.

(Of course, REGEXP_LIKE only matches queries **containing** the search string, so if you want a complete match, you'll have to use `'^$'` for a beginning (`^`) and end (`$`) match, e.g.: `'^regex.*$'`.)