# MySQL regex - Get text in one query

Tags: mysql, regex

Assume we have a table  like this in MySQL

**tbl_test**

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| ID | text                                         |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 1  | Lorem ipsum \n Teacher: Mr. Brown \n Age: 43 | 
| 2  | Dolor \n Teacher: Mrs. Morgan \n Age: 35     | 
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Is it possible to get the name of the teachers with **one single SQL Query**.
The expected result should be:

```
 Mr. Brown
 Mrs. Morgan
```

---

I thought of something like a *regex* SQL query. I have already tried it with `LIKE` but then I get the whole text and not only the teacher's name.

```
SELECT text FROM tbl_test WHERE text LIKE '%Teacher%';
```

**Output**

```
Lorem ipsum \n Teacher: Mr. Brown \n Age: 43
Dolor \n Teacher: Mrs. Morgan \n Age: 35
```

Comment: Your're probably better off fetching the whole text and use php's `explode` or javascript's `split` to get the part you want

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL - Return matching pattern in REGEXP query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361457/mysql-return-matching-pattern-in-regexp-query)

Comment: @g3mini But I want a pure SQL solution

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to regex in a sql query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780194/how-to-regex-in-a-sql-query)

Comment: The better solution is to extract the name _before_ storing into the table.  Then have a column for `name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the pattern is same you can use `substring_index`

```
mysql> select substring_index(substring_index('Lorem ipsum \n Teacher: Mr. Brown \n Age: 43','Teacher:',-1),'\n',1) as teacher;
+-------------+
| teacher     |
+-------------+
|  Mr. Brown  |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)



select
substring_index(substring_index(text,'Teacher:',-1),'\n',1) as teacher_name
from tbl_test ;
```