# PHP search - exclude search results that begin in the middle of a word

Tags: php, search, mysqli

When I search a `query`, I don't want to include results that are within a word.
For example if I type `"Place"` I don't want to include words such as `"Complacent"` that contain the query but don't begin with the query.

Can someone suggest some code that would stop this from happening?

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "movies");
$output = "";
    if(isset($_POST['searchVal'])){
        $searchq = $_POST['searchVal'];
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM movielist WHERE Kids LIKE 'True' AND (Name LIKE '%$searchq%' OR Description LIKE '%$searchq%' OR Year LIKE '%$searchq%' OR Genre LIKE '%$searchq%') ORDER BY Name") or die(mysqli_error());
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
        if($count == 0){
            $output = '<i>Nothing found</i>';
            } 
        else {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            $id = $row['ID'];
            $name = $row['Name'];
            $description = $row['Description'];
            $year = $row['Year'];
            $link = $row['Link'];
            $output .= '<p><a href="../player/?openMovie=' .$link. '"><b>' .$name. '</b><br><i>' .$description. ' - '.$year. '</i></a></p>';    
            }
        }       
    }
echo($output);
?>
```

Comment: [I think you can use REGEXP instead of LIKE.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18780370/2569323)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can omit the leading `%` from your `LIKE` statement. That will force the search to be anchored at the beginning of the field being searched.

```
LIKE 'place%' ...
```

will find *placement*, *place*, but not *complacent*

```
LIKE '%place' ...
```

will find *place*, *commonplace*, but not *complacent*

```
LIKE '%place%' ...
```

will find anything with *place* in it - including *complacent*.

```
LIKE 'place' ...
```

using `LIKE` here is equivalent to using `=`, as it will only find *place*.

**UPDATE**

For finding the search term inside a string, where you want to be certain that the search term is complete (and not part of a longer word), then a simple `LIKE` is not going to do the job.

Using a `REGEXP_LIKE` will work better, and in the regular expression you want to explicitly state that there is a word boundary (or the beginning / end of the string) either side of the search term.

In `mysql`, a regular expression word boundary is denoted by `[[:<:]]` for the beginning of a word, or `[[:>:]]` for the end of a word.

```
...
$query = mysqli_query($conn, 
    "SELECT * FROM movielist WHERE Kids LIKE 'True' 
     AND (REGEXP_LIKE(Name,'([[:<:]]|^)$searchq([[:>:]]|$)') OR 
          REGEXP_LIKE(Description,'([[:<:]]|^)$searchq([[:>:]]|$)') OR
          REGEXP_LIKE(Year,'([[:<:]]|^)$searchq([[:>:]]|$)') OR 
          REGEXP_LIKE(Genre, '([[:<:]]|^)$searchq([[:>:]]|$)'))
     ORDER BY Name") or die(mysqli_error());
...
```

**UPDATE 2**

Noting that `REGEXP_LIKE` is not available in older flavours of `mysql`, the following is an alternative (using `REGEXP`).

```
...
$query = mysqli_query($conn, 
    "SELECT * FROM movielist WHERE Kids LIKE 'True' 
     AND (Name REGEXP '([[:<:]]|^)$searchq([[:>:]]|$)' OR 
          Description REGEXP '([[:<:]]|^)$searchq([[:>:]]|$)' OR
          Year REGEXP '([[:<:]]|^)$searchq([[:>:]]|$)' OR 
          Genre REGEXP '([[:<:]]|^)$searchq([[:>:]]|$)')
     ORDER BY Name") or die(mysqli_error());
...
```

**UPDATE 3**

The following is based on some more information in the comments. The search term is possibly an incomplete word, and as such, it is necessary to look for words which start with the provided search term (even if the search term as such is only a partial word)

```
...
$query = mysqli_query($conn, 
    "SELECT * FROM movielist WHERE Kids LIKE 'True' 
     AND (Name REGEXP '([[:<:]]|^)$searchq' OR 
          Description REGEXP '([[:<:]]|^)$searchq' OR
          Year REGEXP '([[:<:]]|^)$searchq' OR 
          Genre REGEXP '([[:<:]]|^)$searchq')
     ORDER BY Name") or die(mysqli_error());
...
```

Comment: The context of the question is movies, and the keyword needs to appear in either the movie name, description, year, or genre. The original poster wants to match the word "Place", for example, within the context of a sentence but not words like "Complacent" because there's letters directly left and right of it which are part of the same word. But would want to match something like "The place nearest to you." How would this kind of functionality be achievable with `LIKE`? Add a test for spaces? Then a test for new lines? Then a test for quotes, and a test for a comma and period? etc, etc?

Comment: @Ultimater I agree that in your situation, `LIKE` is not going to work.

Comment: The context of the OP's question shows a query `SELECT * FROM movielist WHERE Kids LIKE 'True' AND (Name LIKE '%$searchq%' OR Description LIKE '%$searchq%' OR Year LIKE '%$searchq%' OR Genre LIKE '%$searchq%') ORDER BY Name`. And the code even comes with HTML lower down `/player/?openMovie=` and even a `$_POST['searchVal'` parameter. The context of the question is obviously searching a database full of movie information. While this might not be the real application the OP had in mind, it is the context given to us and thus this is the context we're answering.

Comment: @Ultimater The context is searching a movie database, and this is the actual code that I wish to modify. Is there anything you can suggest

Comment: @PeterAbolins Thank you for your contribution

Comment: @CamAcc You are welcome. My answer doesn't solve your problem?

Comment: @PeterAbolins I wasn't sure on the timeline of comments that were made on this question. I didn't realise that you had made the updates following Ultimater's response.

Comment: @PeterAbolins In regards to whether my problem has been solved - Your response would work well for the scenario which I have provided. However, I haven't mentioned that I use jquery to filter the search after every key-press and it does not work for that as it is looking for a complete word. You have provided some excellent code for me to work with. Thank you.

Comment: @CamAcc Well, I can only work with the information you are happy to provide :) You can actually change the query to fit your situation. Remove the _end-of-word_ placeholders, which will ensure that it will find the words which start with the characters you have already typed.

Comment: @CamAcc I have added another update to cover the new information.

Comment: @PeterAbolins Your third update is just the code I need for the scenario I have described - thank you. I apologise for not providing sufficient information for what I required. Sometimes it's hard to know what you will need to provide for the endless number of possible scenarios.