# How to remove values that contain 'text + numbers' from column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

IN MySQL, I'm trying to remove specific text+number values from a column.  The values are `'US + a number between 1-10'` so something like `'US 1.14'` or `'US 1.25'` etc.  I've been able to remove values that just contain `'US'` but not the ones with `'US [1-10]'`.  Does anyone know the SQL string to remove `'text + numbers'` from a column?

the column is called Geo_Targeting and I've used the following code variations:

```
and GC.Geo_Targeting != '%US [0-9]%'
and GC.Geo_Targeting != 'US %[0-9]%'
```

Ideally, the code would remove any values that contain 'US' or 'US + number' only.

Comment: Are you trying to use `REGEXP`? At least would expect a `LIKE`. Not a equals/not equals.

Comment: Possible dupe of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780194/how-to-regex-in-a-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex pattern will match the values you're looking for:

```
US( \d+.?\d*)?
```

It matches the characters 'US', followed by a space, followed by one or more digits, followed by zero or one '.' characters, followed by zero or more digits. The last ? means that it'll match zero or one of the entire digit group.

You can use it with the NOT_REGEXP function so that you only get values that don't match this pattern (note that '\' characters need to be doubled in mySQL)

```
and GC.Geo_Targeting NOT_REGEXP 'US( \\d+.?\\d*)?'
```

If you need to match values that have this pattern *only*, you can use the '^' character to match the beginning of a line, and the '$' character to match the end.

```
and GC.Geo_Targeting NOT_REGEXP '^US( \\d+.?\\d*)?$'
```

Comment: I gave this a shot and it's saying I have a syntax error.  It says NOT_REGEXP isn't valid at its position

Comment: I don't have MySQL on my computer, so you'll need to do a little troubleshooting yourself. If you google how to use regex in MySQL you'll find plenty of results.

Comment: try withot underscore `not regexp`

Comment: Nice! That's gotten it a little closer but I have some values that say 'US, Canada' or US 1.3, France, Germany 2" etc and those are being removed as well.  Is there a way to keep those and only remove values that have 'US' or 'US + number' only?

Comment: You can use ^ and $ to match the beginning and end of a line respectively. I edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I tried your edit but it's only taking out 'US'.  Values with 'US + number' only and multi-country values still show

Comment: Again, I don't have MySQL installed, so you'll need to do some troubleshooting on your own. Here's a regex testing site, showing how this pattern matches the examples you've shown: https://regexr.com/45qfk