# SQL: Select with "Like" 2 elements

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, sql-like

How can I select any person that has two letters "a" in the name, on a PostgreSQL database ?
I try `select client from xclient where client like '%a%'` but this return all people that contain "a" in the name. I necessarily need to use "Like".

Should the results include people with two 'a's in their name
Example: "Marta".
Can't include "Alaia" for example.

Comment: Should the results include people with three 'a's in their name?

Comment: In Danish, consecutive 'aa' is considered to be one character, 'å' (i.e. not two 'a'.)

Comment: @HappyMoose Should the results include people with two 'a's in their name 
Example: "Marta".
Can't include "Alaia" for example.

Comment: Part of the issue here is that you're being very imprecise.  What are the ***full and exact*** business rules that you're trying to implement?

Comment: That's simple, limit of "A" in the name must be two and minimal must two.
Correct Example "Marta".
Incorrect Example: "Angalaia" or "Aana"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question and comments are very vague.

My interpretation is that...

You consider `A` and `a` to be the same character

- So, you should use `ILIKE` not `LIKE`

You want names with two `A` or `a`, but not more than two, and it doesn't matter if they're next to each other.

```
WITH
  xclient AS
(
            SELECT 'Baat'   AS client
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Marta'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Alaia'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Angalaia'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Aana'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Arcanjamana'
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  xclient
WHERE
      client     ILIKE '%a%a%'
  AND client NOT ILIKE '%a%a%a%'
```

Demo : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a0894fdd211087db552537e40d28d9bf

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select client from xclient where client like '%a%a%'
```

Comment: This is the return of all people with two "a"s in a row.
Example: "Aana"

Comment: @VictorHugo - `LIKE '%a%a%' AND NOT LIKE '%a%a%a%'` will get everyone with two `a`'s in their name, but exclude anyone with 3 or more `a`'s in their name.  That will exclude `Aana`, but what do you want to do with `Baat`?

Comment: @MatBailie That's include for example "Aangala". The limit is two "A" and minimal is two "A"

Comment: It absolutely does NOT include `Aangala` the `NOT LIKE` explicitly excludes it.

Answer (score 0):

I am almost sure this code works in the examples you said:

```
select client from xclient where client like '%a%a%' and client not like '%a%a%a%' and client not like '%a%aa%' and client not like '%aa%a%' and client not like '%aa%aa%'
```

There is no doubt that you could optimize this code using [the substring keyword](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_substring.asp), but, anyway, this should perform as you wished.

Comment: That's include for example "Aangala". The limit is two "A" and minimal is two "A"

Comment: Try the new code (I edited my answer).

Comment: Yes, that's is correct, but if the name is "Arcanjamana" ?
You understand that i need a limitator ?

Comment: I can't edit my code every time someone enters a different name.

Comment: Okay, now I got what you mean. In your question, even though you specify two examples you do not want to appear, _Marta_ and _Alaia_, you only state that you **do not want two a's**, that is why we all got confused. Now, understanding the issue, I suggest you checking [REGEXP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) to address this problem. You got an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780194/how-to-regex-in-a-mysql-query). I also encourage you to use [this website](https://regex101.com/) to do your tests. Hope it helps!